# Sum integers in delimited string

Tags: java, string, integer, sum

Given a delimiter `String` as input, add all the numbers together.

For example:

```
addNumbers("12 24 36") -> 72 
addNumbers("12 12 100") -> 124
```

I am getting number format exception when i try this.

```
String a="12 34 4 676";
String b=a.replaceAll(" ", "+");
long num=Long.parseLong(a);
```

Comment: Split the string by spaces, parse each part to int and add them together

Comment: So if you input `"12  34"` you want `12++34` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because `12+34+4+676` is not a number, it's an expression.

In Java 8 you could do something like:

```
final int sum = Stream.of(a.split("\\s")).
        mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).
        sum();
```

In Java 7 you could do:

```
int sum = 0;
for (final String s : a.split("\\s")) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

OP's comment: *i dont want to use array*.

I like a challenge, so here is a solution that uses a `Scanner`:

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(a);
int sum = 0;
while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    sum += scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: +1 for Java 8. It's going to take me a while to get used to Java's new Haskell-like capabilities.

Comment: i dont want to use array

Comment: @SumitKumarJadhav and what do you _want_ to use? If you have restrictions of what you are allowed to use they should be part of the question.

Comment: No arrays, Only String and all String methods, and old styled for loop

Comment: and cant use scanner also

Comment: @SumitKumarJadhav As far as I see it `split` is a `String` method. Make your requirements more clear. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parse a string that contains operators to directly get the value. Split it using `split("\\s")` and then loop through the array and find the sum.

Comment: if i loop through i ll get sum of individual chars, here i want the sum of numbers spaced

Comment: @SumitKumarJadhav `str.split("\\s")` returns a String array. He is suggesting that you loop through _that_.